# change of variables on integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Please explain how this equality came

$$
\int_{|z| \le R} \frac{dz}{|z|^\alpha}
 = \int_{S^1} dS \int_0^R \frac{r^{m-1}}{r^{\alpha}} dr$$

I don't understand how degree $m-1$ came about. 
Sorry for my English

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the 2D case, you get $dz=rdrdt$ so the integral ends up
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} dt  \int_0^R \frac{rdr}{r^\alpha}
$$
where $r = r^{2-1}$ in the numerator comes from taking the Jacobian from orthogonal to polar coordinates.

In 3D you will convert to spherical, etc. The $r^{m-1}$ is coming from the Jacobian.

Comment: Thank you for answering me! Can you tell me please, what kind of change of variables is done?

Comment: @Simurgh you are going from rectangular to spherical (in 2D case $dz=dxdy$ to $rdrdt$)